# What content should go in index.php?

Tags: page-template

I'm developing my own theme and came up with an issue that' I am confused with. I have two files that I'm trying to figure out. `page.php` and `index.php`.

I know that page.php is used for pages, of course, but when trying to set up a 404 page, for example:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


    <section class="main-content">
        <div class="content-wrap">
            <div class="module page">
                <h1 class="title"><?php wp_title(''); ?></h1>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div><!-- /.blog -->
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div><!-- /.content-wrap -->
    </section>

<?php endwhile; else : ?>
404 not found
<?php endif; ?>
```

Nothing will be displayed. Now, if I copy this content and stick it in index.php, I will have a 404 page. I have no idea what to do because index.php is required for a theme but I don't know what to do with it. Can someone explain the differences and what kind of content actually goes in it?

Answer (score 1):

Index.php isn't for a specific page, and that's not how template files in themes work.

You will need to understand the template heirarchy

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

[image]

> WordPress uses the Query String — information contained within each
>   link on your web site — to decide which template or set of templates
>   will be used to display the page.
>
> First, WordPress matches every Query String to query types — i.e. it
>   decides what type of page (a search page, a category page, the home
>   page etc.) is being requested.
>
> Templates are then chosen — and web page content is generated — in the
>   order suggested by the WordPress Template hierarchy, depending upon
>   what templates are available in a particular WordPress Theme.
>
> WordPress looks for template files with specific names in the current
>   Theme's directory and uses the first matching template file listed
>   under the appropriate query section below.
>
> With the exception of the basic index.php template file, Theme
>   developers can choose whether they want to implement a particular
>   template file or not. If WordPress cannot find a template file with a
>   matching name, it skips down to the next file name in the hierarchy.
>   If WordPress cannot find any matching template file, index.php (the
>   Theme's home page template file) will be used.

Answer (score 0):

**[Ian Stewart's WordPress THEME DEVELOPMENT TUTORIAL](http://themeshaper.com/2009/06/22/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/)** will surely help you the most.
It presents a nice theme for me.